# Calculating the convergence order in inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence, optimization, logarithms

Given a constant $0<\epsilon<1$, I want to solve the following inequality
$$
\frac{\ln(K)}{K} \leq \epsilon, ~~K\in \Bbb N^+. 
$$
I wish to find some relationship like $K\geq \log(\epsilon^{-1})\epsilon^{-1}$ or something else.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need all solutions to the inequality or just *some* solution.  In the latter case, $K=1$ will do for all $\epsilon$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spoiler:** Suppose $0<\epsilon < 1/e$, then it is sufficient to take

$$K_0 = \frac1\epsilon\Big(\sqrt{-2(1+\ln\epsilon)}-\ln\epsilon\Big)$$
to get $\dfrac{\ln K}K < \epsilon$ for all $K\geqslant K_0$.
If $\epsilon \geqslant 1/e$ then you can take any $K$ you like.

---

In order to see this, prepare the inequality so that [Lambert $W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) can be applied:

$$\begin{align}
f(K) := \frac{\ln K} K &\leqslant \epsilon && \text{multiply with } K > 0 \tag1\\
\ln K &\leqslant \epsilon K && \text{apply exp} \tag2\\
K &\leqslant \exp (\epsilon K) && \text{divide by right side} \tag3\\
K \exp (-\epsilon K) &\leqslant 1 && \text{multiply by } -\epsilon\tag4\\
-\epsilon K \exp (-\epsilon K) &\geqslant -\epsilon && \text{apply Lambert } W_0 \tag5\\
-\epsilon K &\geqslant W_0(-\epsilon) && \text{divide by } -\epsilon \tag6\\
K &\leqslant -\frac{W_0(-\epsilon)}\epsilon \tag7\\
\end{align}$$

Applying $\exp$ to $(2)$ does not flip the inequality sign because $\exp$ is an increasing function.
Same for applying $W_0$ in step $(5)$.

In order to apply $W$ we must have $-\epsilon \geqslant -1/e$ so that $\epsilon \leqslant 1/e\approx 0.36788$.

For real values, Lambert $W$ has a second branch $W_{-1}$ that's monotonically decreasing, so that we could proceed

$$\begin{align}
-\epsilon K \exp (-\epsilon K) &\geqslant -\epsilon && \text{apply Lambert } W_{-1} \tag{5'}\\
-\epsilon K &\leqslant W_{-1}(-\epsilon) && \text{divide by } -\epsilon \tag{6'}\\
K &\geqslant -\frac{W_{-1}(-\epsilon)}\epsilon \tag{7'}\\
\end{align}$$

Taking it all together:

- If $\epsilon \geqslant 1/e\approx0.36788$ then there is no restriction on $K$. Notice that $(e,1/e)$ is the global maximum of $f:x\mapsto x^{-1}\ln x$.
- Otherwise, $K\leqslant \operatorname{floor}(-\epsilon^{-1}W_0(-\epsilon))$ or $K\geqslant \operatorname{ceil}(-\epsilon^{-1}W_{-1}(-\epsilon))$.

The fact that $K$ is a Natural number means that $\operatorname{floor}(-\epsilon^{-1}W_0(-\epsilon))\in\{1,2\}$ because $1$ and $2$ are the only Natural numbers that are smaller than $e$. $K=1$ will always satisfy the inequality because $\ln 1 = 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

For branch $W_{-1}$ this doesn't gain you much, it just tells you that $K\geqslant 3$ is necessary (but not sufficient), but for the exact value you'll have to invoke inequality $(7')$ resp. ceil of that value.  This branch will contribute infinitely many values for $K$: If the original inequality is true for some $K_0\geqslant e$, then it also holds for all $K\geqslant K_0$.  This is true because $f:x\mapsto x^{-1}\ln x$ is monotonically decreasing for $x\geqslant e$.

---

There is a way to make this a bit more explicit / computable, so let's determine some $K_0$ such that $f(K) < \epsilon$ for all $K > K_0(\epsilon)$:

Let $0<\epsilon < 1/e$ and $u=-1-\ln\epsilon$.  Then we have:

$$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-\epsilon) \tag 8$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Bounds_and_inequalities) for example. Then take:

$$K_0:=\frac1\epsilon (1+\sqrt{2u}+u) > -\frac1\epsilon W_{-1}(-\epsilon) \tag 9$$
This means when we chose $K_0$ as the left side of $(9)$, then for all $K\geqslant K_0$ we have that $f(K) < \epsilon$. Some examples:

```
 ϵ      u            K_0  f(K_0)   smallest K
---------------------------------------------
0.1     1.303     39.167  0.0937          36
0.01    3.605    729.038  0.00905        648
0.001   5.908  10345.125  0.000894      9119
```

This shows that using $K_0$ according to $(9)$ is not that far off the smallest possible $K$.

Also notice that the order of approximation in $(8)$ cannot be substancially improved since for $u>0$ (i.e. $\epsilon < 1/e$):

$$-u < W_{-1}(-\epsilon) +1+\sqrt{2u} < -\frac23 u$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a>1,\varepsilon>0$ let's consider equality
$$\frac{K}{a^{K\varepsilon}} = \frac{K}{(1+a^{\varepsilon}-1)^K}=\frac{K}{1+K(a^{\varepsilon}-1)+\frac{K(K-1)}{2}\cdot (a^{\varepsilon}-1)^2+\cdots+(a^{\varepsilon}-1)^K}$$
from which we have
$$\frac{K}{a^{K\varepsilon}}<\frac{2}{(K-1)\cdot (a^{\varepsilon}-1)^2}$$
So, when
$$\frac{2}{(K-1)\cdot (a^{\varepsilon}-1)^2}<1\Leftrightarrow K>\frac{2}{ (a^{\varepsilon}-1)^2}+1\quad (1)$$
then holds
$$\frac{K}{a^{K\varepsilon}}<1\Leftrightarrow \frac{\log_a K}{K}<\varepsilon\quad (2)$$

In your case $a=e$, so $(1)$ becomes $K>\frac{2}{ (e^{\varepsilon}-1)^2}+1$.

Shortly: $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$

Comment: I am not sure I understand the correspondence between your setup and the original question. I guess you you looked at $\ln(K)/(K\epsilon) < 1$ and then your $n$ is $\ln(K)$?

Comment: @Ian.
I rewrite it in question terms: $K>\frac{2}{ (e^{\varepsilon}-1)^2}+1$ implies $\frac{\ln K}{K}<\varepsilon$. Hope, now is everything clear.